# Trying to understand zlib/deflate in PNG files

Tags: encoding, png, implementation, deflate

I'm currently in the middle of writing a small PNG image I/O library myself for learning purposes. My problem is the following:

I created a small PNG only 2 by 2 pixels in dimension and opened it in a hex editor to study its contents. This is the image I created using GIMP and stored with a compression of "9".

(Please note that this is an enlarged image of the original 2 by 2 pixel image ;) )

[image: a black, red, blue and green pixel in a two by two array of pixels.]

So I guess uncompressed, this would look something like this in memory:

```
00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 FF 00
```

when stored without an alpha channel.

(I only stated this here for clarity. I know of compression and did not expect to see this byte pattern in the file).

I extracted the IDAT chunk and stripped the chunk ID ("IDAT") and the tailing CRC value and got this sequence of bytes:

```
08 D7 05 C1 01 01 00 00 00 80 10 FF 4F 17 10 48 06 0F FE 02 FE
```

Now the first two bytes `08 D7` contain information on the encoded block.
And the last four bytes `0F FE 02 FE` must be the ADLER32 checksum.

This ultimately leaves me with the following bytes:

```
05 C1 01 01 00 00 00 80 10 FF 4F 17 10 48 06
```

Written in binary representation these bytes are:

```
0000 0101  1100 0001  0000 0001  0000 0001
0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  1000 0000
0001 0000  1111 1111  0100 1111  0001 0111
0001 0000  0100 1000  0000 0110
```

To understand DEFLATE better I tried to "unpack" this sequence by hand at least before I understand it well enough to write a small tool. But I got stuck really quickly.

RFC 1951 (["DEFLATE Compressed Data Format Specification"](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt)) states that every encoded block begins with a three bit header. One bit indicating whether or not this is the last block and two more blocks indicating the compression method. Since I assume the encoder used only one block here (meaning the first block automatically is the last) and used a non static Huffmann tree, I am looking for the bit sequence "101" but I cannot find it (nor do I find other likely headers "100" or "110").

Also the RFC says that there must be two two byte values LEN and NLEN storing the length of the block where NLEN is the one's complement of LEN but again I am unable to find four such bytes that satisfy this condition. I won't even start on my luck of finding anything that could represend the two Huffmann trees.

I read RFCs 1951 and 1950 (["ZLIB Compressed Data Format Specification"](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt) as well as the Wikipedia articles on zlib, DEFLATE, LZ77 and Huffman coding, as well as several small and rather unhelpful articles on the web and a few answers on Stack Overflow, but none could help me with my lack of understanding.

I would be really grateful for any help or hint!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are missing how bits are packed inside bytes (see eg section 3.1.1 of [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt))

```
 Data elements are packed into bytes in order of
 increasing bit number within the byte, i.e., starting
 with the least-significant bit of the byte.
```

Hence, if the first byte is 05 =  0000 0101   the first bit is 1.

(BTW, it's surely quite instructive to look things at so much detail, but I wonder if you are not going a little too far if your intent is to understand PNG. )

Further, when you come to the point were you find the uncompressed IDAT stream, bear in mind that the pixels are coded with one of five [filters](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Filters.html) per row, and that there is an extra byte at the start of each row that signals the filter type. So, you won't really find the raw 12 bytes `00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 FF 00`, but 12+2=14 bytes instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right I did not think of the bit ordering inside bytes. I'm aware of the filters and only included this little example to show what I'm expecting in the end after decompressing and removing the filters ;-) .. could as well have left this snippet out.

Comment: Now that we have the header. Am I right that the following zeroes are the representation of the first huffmann tree ? (BTW, Yes it is  very low level and I'm certainly not doing this again on another image format but I want to understand whats going on at this level at least once ;-) ).

Comment: If you want a detailed explanation, I recommend http://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Image-File-Formats-JPEG/dp/0201604434/ref=pd_sim_b_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=05VHZ02D8BR9MJCQNK3W

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm not an expert on deflate, perhaps you should ask a new question for that (remember: this is not chat forum). Here you can get answers from real experts, as Mr Adler himself :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/users/1180620/mark-adler

Comment: That's Dr. Adler to you.

Answer (score 9):

In case this helps, here is a disassembly of the IDAT chunk contents:

```
! infgen 2.2 output
!
zlib
!
last
dynamic
count 257 2 18
code 1 1
code 2 2
code 18 2
lens 1
zeros 138
zeros 116
lens 2 2 1 1
! litlen 0 1
! litlen 255 2
! litlen 256 2
! dist 0 1
! dist 1 1
literal 0 0 0 0 255 0 0 0 0 0 255 0 255 0
end
!
adler
```

You can get the `infgen` source code [here](http://zlib.net/infgen.c.gz).

Comment: Is that an autograph at the bottom, or just a confirmation the last 2 words were encoded correctly?

Comment: It is not a confirmation, but just a statement that there are four bytes there where the Adler-32 is supposed to be.  `infgen` does not compute the check value on the uncompressed data to see if it's correct.