# IDAT Chunk of PNG File Format

Tags: c, png, deflate

I am currently developing a proprietary file format based on the png file format. I am done so far, except it doesn't work :-p The deflate decompressor I implemented works like a charm but the png decoder doesn't want to perform nicely so I took a look at the original png file.

The standard says that after a IDAT header, the compressed data is following immediatly. So as the data is a deflate stream the first char after IDAT is 0x78 == 01111000 which means, a mode one block (uncompressed) and its not the final one.

Strange though - its hard for me to imagine that a PNG encoder doesn't use dynamic huffman coding for compressing the filtered raw image data. The deflate standard says that the rest of the current byte is skipped in mode one.

So the next four bytes indicate the size of the uncompressed block and its one complement.
But 0x59FD is not the one complement of 0xECDA. Even if I screwed up the byte ordering: 0xFD59 is not the one complement of 0xDAEC either.

Well, the knockout byte just follows. 0x97 is considered to be the first byte of the uncompressed but still filtered raw png image data and as such must be the filtertype. But 0x97 == 10010111 is not a valid filter type. Event if I screwed up bit packing order 11101001 == 0xe9 is still no valid filter type.

I didn't focus on RFC 1951 much anymore as I am able to inflate all kind of files so far using my implementation of the deflate decompressor, so I suspect some misunderstanding on my part concering the PNG standard.

I read the RFC 2083 over and over again but the data I see here don't match the RFC,  it doesn't make sense to me, there must be a missing piece!

When I look at the following bytes, I can actually not see a valid filter type byte anywhere near which makes me think that the filtered png data stream is nevertheless compressed after all.

It would make sense if 0x78 (the first byte after IDAT) would be read from MSB to LSB but RFC 1951 says otherwise. Another idea (more likely to me) is that there some data between the IDAT string and the start of the compressed deflate stream but RFC 2083 says otherwise. The Layout is clear

4Bytes Size
4Bytes ChunkName (IDAT)
[Size] Bytes (compressed deflate stream)
4Bytes CRC Checksum

So the first byte after IDAT must be the first byte of the compressed deflate stream - which indicates a mode 1 uncompressed data block. Which means that 0x97 must be the first byte of uncompressed but filtered png image data - which means 0x97 is the filtertype for the first row - which is invalid...

I just don't get it, am I stupid or what??

Summary:
Possibility 1:
There is some other data between IDAT and the effective start of the compressed deflate stream which, if renders to be true, is not meantioned in the RFC2083 nor in any book I read about image compression.

Possibility 2:
The number 0x78 is interpreted MSB -> LSB which would indicate a mode 3 block (dynamic huffman coding), but this contradicts with RF1951 which is very clear about Bit packing: (LSB -> MSB)

I know already, the missing piece must be something very stupid and I will feel the urgend need to sell my soul if there was only a delete button in Stack Overflow :-p

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two corrections which may help you get you on your way:

1. The number of `zlib` bytes in the flags is 2, not 1 -- see [RFC 1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950). The first is `CMF`, the next `FLG`.

In your data:

```
78 DA

---CMF---  ---FLG---
0111.1000  1101.0101
CINF -CM-  +-||
           | |+- FCHECK
           | +-- FDICT
           +---- FLEVEL
```

`CINF` is 7, indicating the standard 32Kb compression window.
`CM` is 8, indicating the compression algorithm is, indeed, DEFLATE.
`FCHECK` is just a checksum; I didn't check if it's correct (but I'd bet it is).
`FDICT` is clear, meaning there is no preset dictionary stored.
`FLEVEL` is 3, indicating Maximum Compression.

See also [Trying to understand zlib/deflate in PNG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018811/trying-to-understand-zlib-deflate-in-png-files), esp. dr. Adler's answer.

2. `LEN` and `NLEN` are only set for uncompressed blocks; that's why you didn't find them. (Also, partially, because you were looking at the wrong byte(s).)

The next *byte* in the stream is `EC`; bitwise, this is `1110 1100` *but* remember to read bits from low to high. So the next bit read is `0`, meaning *not* FINAL, and the next 2 bits read are `10` (in that order!), indicating a regular dynamic Huffman encoded data block.

Comment: I didn't realize the deflate stream is wrapped within a zlib container. I assumed its a pure deflate stream. So I now simply skipped the two bytes and voila - the png importer works! :-) Thanks a lot!